# How to fetch an array from db and show it in table in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Hey there i am working on a project and i have saved some data in an array which i would like to show in a table below is the array.

[{"medicine":["Azax 500 Tablet","Benadryl Syrup","Bro-Zedex Syrup"],"dosage":["1 pill","1 pill A","1 pill B"],"timing":["Twice a day","Twice a day A","Twice a day B"],"duration":["1 week","1 week A","1 week B"]}]

I tried getting the data but the result i got was not ideal.
Hear is my controller code

```
$PrescId = $Request->id;
$PrescDetails = DB::table('prescriptionunrege')->where('id',$PrescId)->first();
$Prescription = DB::table('prescriptionunrege')->where('id',$PrescId)->get();
return view('test',compact('PrescDetails','Prescription'));
```

hear is my blade file code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Name: {{ $PrescDetails->Name }}</div>  
    <div>Contact: {{ $PrescDetails->Contact }}</div>  
    <div>Gender: {{ $PrescDetails->Gender }}</div>  
    <div>Age: {{ $PrescDetails->Age }}</div>  
    <div>Diagnosis: {{ $PrescDetails->Diagnosis }}</div>  
    <div>{{ $PrescDetails->Prescription }}</div>
    <div style="margin-top: 55px">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Medicine</th>
                <th>Dosage</th>
                <th>Timing</th>
                <th>Duration</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach ($Prescription as $item)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $item->Prescription[0] }}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hear is my output

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iBaE4HqbLBnj1cH56uDlUqL3UYoVfED8/view?usp=sharing

any help is really appreciated. Thankyou

Comment: you can show, what is your result in table rows?

Comment: IDK where is your issue but if you want the result as an `Array` you must use the `toArray` method https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-toarray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating for prescription items, and showing first index of them,

if your result is expected as you want and just table is showing bad, you must use a `<td>` for each of `dosage, timing, duration`

or if your result show only `medicine` items and not more,

you must show same index in other sections (`dosage, timing, duration`)

because i don't know your exact problem, and a result example, i can't modify code...

show response of

```
            @foreach ($Prescription as $item)
                <tr>
                    @dd($item, $Prescription)
                    <td>{{ $item->Prescription[0] }}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
```

not clear question at all, after showing result in comments, use this block code :

```
@foreach ($Prescription as $item)
    @php($nPrescription = json_decode($item->Prescription, true))
    @foreach($nPrescription[0]['medicine'] as $index => $medicine)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $medicine }}</td>
            <td>{{ $nPrescription[0]['dosage'][$index] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $nPrescription[0]['timing'][$index] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $nPrescription[0]['duration'][$index] }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: can you show @dd($item, $Prescription) in loop?

Comment: sorry i didn't get you i am a noob

Comment: use block code shown in answer, and share result.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MjVVaJcNiusPSFf-SXVzQRKs6RhxtdVE/view?usp=sharing     Hear is what you want

Comment: thanks, you can use @dd($item->Prescription) and show result.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Frroz4DcfZ9VEnK8ISmubtXy06dGXbiX/view?usp=sharing hear it is

Comment: @HarishSharma updated answer, use last block code.

Comment: Bro that worked thanks pal. Can you please explain the code a little for my future reference

Comment: @HarishSharma can you mark as answer?!
Ok, simple, you need to desterilize array, or use laravel $casts,
so iterate for medicine and get exact index in other arrays.